# How do I include the computer's domain name in the NServiceBus ReplyToAddress?

Tags: nservicebus

I'm using NServiceBus with MSMQ and I'm trying to send a message from a computer in one domain to another computer in a different domain. A trust exists between the two domains.

The two computers can ping each other, but only if they use the fully-qualified name of the computer, e.g. pc01.mydomain.net.

In the config file on the computer that sends the message, I've ensured my MessageEndpointMappings are correct by setting the Endpoint attribute to be "Endpoint@pc01.mydomain.net". If I try to send a message then it arrives OK at the pc01 endpoint.

However, when the pc01 endpoint tries to send the reply back to the sender (let's say that computer's name is sender01.anotherdomain.net) it fails to deliver the message. When I check Bus.CurrentMessageContext.ReplyToAddress it returns "queuename@sender01". I believe (although I can't prove it) that if the ReplyToAddress was "queuename@sender01.anotherdomain.net" then the reply would arrive in the correct queue as desired.

So I just need a way to ensure the ReplyToAddress has the fully-quailfied name of the computer (sender01.anotherdomain.net) rather than just the computer name (sender01).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an outgoing transport message mutator on the sender that updates the ReplyToAddress accordingly.

In v4 you can override the way we resolve machine names by changing the RuntimeEnvironment.MachineNameAction func.